# SSH via Java with Environment Variables

Tags: java, shell, variables, ssh, environment

I am writing a java code to connect to the Unix remote server using java-ganymed plugin (also tried with JSch).

```
    Connection conn = new Connection("host");
    conn.connect();
    boolean testAuth = conn.authenticateWithPassword("user", "pwd");
    Session sess = conn.openSession();
    sess.execCommand(Commands); //"Commands" is a string variable with "sh" command.
```

I need to run a shell script located at the remote server, which uses some Environment Variables of that login. My login is successful and script does execute but not to completion. I checked that the environment variables are not completely loaded as compared to running an interactive login shell like Putty etc(used 'env' command).

I tried running /etc/profile, .bashrc etc prior to my script. The script moves one step ahead but again halts. So its evident that a few environment variables were loaded but not all. I need a work around to ensure all the environment variables are loaded for the Java non-interactive session. I do NOT have the root permission for the remote server.

Thanks,
Arya

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run `/etc/profile` and `.bashrc`, try using them as source scripts. Execute this as part of your script or command:

```
. .bashrc
. /etc/profile
. /etc/environment
```

or any other relevant config script (the dot ad the beggining of the file is important).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried adding these to the beginning of my shell script. Again, there a few environment variables that are not initialized. I'm not sure on which ones though. Is there anyway I check what are the ones I need to run explicitly, which run on normal interactive login.